# Why are is there a 3 by featured when only 2 questions have bounties?

Tags: bug

[image: featured]

It's a pretty obvious bug. If you click on the [complete list](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=featured) link it shows only two also.

Comment: probably caching, SE caches *everything* and occasionally this leads to such discrepancies.

Answer (score 1):

See: [Featured Question count is incorrect](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38500/featured-question-count-is-incorrect)

It seems that questions with bounties that are highly downvoted won't be displayed on the featured tab, but will still affect the count.

However, that doesn't *fully* explain the problem, given this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Caching? Hidden tags?

Works on my machine™

[image]